# Objective C Data Caching on iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am pulling data from an API and then building out my data objects with it.  I want to cache this data for the future.  I have been storing the string from the api in NSUserDefaults and then re-parsing it each time the app loads.  This works, but it really seems like the wrong way to go about it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many different solutions to this problem and there is no "right" way to do it. A few popular options are:

- [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) - Apple's framework for persistence. Very performant, but more difficult.
- [SQLite](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app) - Fast and flexible, but bare bones.
- [Plists](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) - Basically writing a file to disk, you have to read and write manually.
- [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - The lightest weight "key-value" option.

I would encourage you to read up on all four and see which one works best for you.

Comment: I'd like to add Realm to your list as well.

Answer (score 15):

Have you noticed the [NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

> An `NSCache` object is a mutable collection that stores key-value pairs, similar to an [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary) object. The `NSCache` class provides a programmatic interface to adding and removing objects and setting eviction policies based on the total cost and number of objects in the cache...

Comment: That's new to 10.6 and iOS 4.0 though, so not necessarily available (at least for now, Apple will still accept application submissions with deployment targets as low as 3.1). Though based on market share and missing like NSCache, I don't think that developing a new app for 3.1 is really a smart decision.

Comment: As I understand the question, what is desired in this case is ***persistent cache***. The `NSCache` is in-memory cache, basically `NSDictionary` that can discard cached data in low memory conditions.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I'm quite fond of the EGOCache classes, I use them quite a lot in my projects:

https://github.com/enormego/EGOCache

The classes are easy to use, I used to have my own classes with a similar design, but these are just more well-rounded, so I decided to stick with them (don't wanna reinvent the wheel).

Answer (score 5):

I vote [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Answer (score 0):

What type of data? If its text/string bases SQLLite would probably be the best.

Answer (score 0):

I'd store the computed/parsed data in either a Core Data store, or in NSData flat files in your application's Documents directory.  You're correct that storing that in NSUserDefaults and then re parsing feels a little overkill.