# How can I pre-load a UITableView before pushing its UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

**Background:** The basic idea of the idea of the app is sending content to friends in a manner similar to Snapchat. The app is already functional, but now I'm attempting some performance improvements. Right now, after selecting the "next" button on the screen where content is generated, there is a delay because the view controller that is being pushed has to load a UITableView of around 30 cells. This was my previous attempt to speed up the transition:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     self.selectFriendsViewController = [[MPOSelectFriendsViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"MPOSelectFriendsViewController"
                                        bundle:nil];
     [self.selectFriendsViewController awakeFromNib]; 
}
```

When the next button is pressed:

```
- (void)gotoFriendsPage {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectFriendsViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**What I'm looking to do:** Snapchat somehow has the friend's list preloaded at all times with zero delay as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPMI5.jpg

Obviously they're using a UIPageViewController instead of a UINavigationController for that kind of effect but my questions are really these:

**1.** If I change my backing controller from a UINavigationController to UIPageViewController, will this kind of zero delay loading be automatic?

**2.** Is there a way to get a zero delay load time like this with a UINavigationController?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**Edit:** Request for my table view cellForRowAtIndexPathCode:

```
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FriendSelectionCell";

    MPOFriendSelectionCell *cell = (MPOFriendSelectionCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[MPOFriendSelectionCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
     }
     MPOUser *friend = [self.friendManager.recentFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     if(friend != (MPOUser *)[NSNull null]) {
         cell.currentFriend = friend;
         cell.friendLabel.text = friend.fullName;
     }
     return cell;
```

Comment: Can you give your table view cellforrowatindexpath code?

Comment: It shouldn't load all 30 cells, but just the ones on the screen if you write it correctly.

Comment: Just added. You're right it doesn't actually load all 30 cells at once.

Comment: iOS 6.1 Minimum required version for the app is 6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no single-step solution to this.
You need to implement caching, and immediately display that information on the UI when it loads. There's a lot of ways to cache data. You can either use NSUserDefaults (I don't recommend this for big data) or a [host of other caching methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733725/objective-c-data-caching-on-ios). After that, you need to lazy-load all of the new information and figure out a smart way to update information on cells already representing data, and insert new rows for data that's new and not yet represented in the UITableView.

The calls that will be relevant in your case would be:

1. [[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)
2. [[UITableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)
3. [[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: withRowAnimation:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:)

The above methods take in an array of index paths and a UITableViewRowAnimation. For index paths, you can do something like `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0], /*and so on*/ nil];`

I suggest using a `UITableViewRowAnimationFade` for reloaded rows, and `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` / `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom` for inserting or deleting rows.

When you initially load up the view controller, use cached information to render the cells. In your viewDidLoad, spawn off a background call that downloads / loads up the new data and once that's completed, update your UITableView on the fly.

The only drawback here is that on first load, there will be no data to show. You can side step this by loading up some default or placeholder data so that the user has something to play around with while you load up actual data.

I'm sorry that there's not much code I can post here. Your question doesn't have a single catch-all solution and there's multiple ways you could tackle this problem. My answer is the best way I'd do this, but I'm sure there's many other ways you could solve this problem.

**Also, run the time profiler in instruments... it will help you see what part of your app consumes the most time.**

Comment: Thanks for the response sid. I'm currently caching the data in my friend manager using `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.friends toFile:[self friendArchivePath]];` but even if the friends list doesn't change, It's still slow each time I hit "back", then "next" again.

Comment: In MPOFriendSelectionCell, I see you have a setter for 'currentFriend'. Does that setter do anything custom? Could you post code from your cell's implementation file? The reason I ask is because as of now, it seems like you're only updating the text on the UILabel for the cell. In that case there should be no delay. Also, when you read data from your FriendsManager using MPOUser *friend = '[self.friendManager.recentFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];', is that reading the cached copy on disk? Repeated accesses to your cache could be slow. How about pre-loading all of the info in an Array?

Comment: Also, run the time profiler in instruments... it will help you see what part of your app consumes the most time.

Comment: Wow that helped so much! After running the profiler, I realized that viewWillAppear was taking the most time because I was calling `[self refresh]` there. After moving that method call to viewDidAppear, all the caching I did did it's job. The transition is now instant!

Comment: I wish I could give you an up-vote but I don't have enough reputation yet X_X

Comment: No worries, Mike :) Glad it helped solve your issue. I'll add the time profiler tip in the answer. Cheers!

Comment: I'll give ya one.  Using Profiler is an absolute necessity if you want a quality app.

Comment: ElJay, I completely agree. I can't stress enough on the importance of instruments, and I find it surprising that it's not as widely used as it should be.

Comment: In addition, I added these 4 lines to the previous screen, which really increased the speed `[self.selectFriendsViewController awakeFromNib];
    [self.selectFriendsViewController.view awakeFromNib];
    [self.selectFriendsViewController loadView];
    [self.selectFriendsViewController viewDidLoad];`

Comment: I would recommend against that, actually. loadView and viewDidLoad are called automatically as part of the UIViewController lifecycle. Move any relevant code in those methods that you think could be called before pushing and move it into your own methods and call those instead. This way, you don't interfere with the normal operation of the UIViewController. I think calling awakeFromNib is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The method that I have adopted for situations like this (where I am getting data from an external source) is to save the `Array` used for the `TableView` datasource to `NSUserDefaults` and then load that first when the `viewDidLoad` fires.  After that I call my web-service to get fresh data and compare the `Array` loaded from `NSUserDefaults` to the just downloaded `Array` I got from the web-service.  If they are equal, do nothing.  If they are different, update the `TableView` and save the newest data back to `NSUserDefaults`.

This works fast and great even for large datasets (8000 records).

Comment: That definitely sounds like it could speed it up. Currently I cache the data in the friend manager using '[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.friends toFile:[self friendArchivePath]];' Is 'NSUserDefaults' faster?

Comment: I haven't done performance testing versus file based caching, but I would bet it is. All you are doing is (at most) replacing an array with a new array.  I have one app that caches an 8000 row array (phonebook) and it is almost imperceptible when it loads new data.